# how to sort results from full text search query

Tags: python, google-app-engine, full-text-search

I'm testing the fulltext search python api of Google App Angine.
The api search engine works fine, but I could not manage to get ordered results, following the basic steps described at: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/sortexpressionclass

The search function is really simple, but sort_options does not look to make any difference

```
    def FindDocuments(self, query_string, limit):
    try:
        sort_options=search.SortOptions(expressions=[search.SortExpression(expression='comment', default_value='',direction=search.SortExpression.ASCENDING)])           
        query_options = search.QueryOptions(limit=limit,sort_options=sort_options)
        query_obj = search.Query(query_string=query_string, options=query_options)
        return search.Index(name=_INDEX_NAME).search(query=query_obj)
    except search.Error:
        logging.exception('Search failed')
    return None
```

Searching for the word 'item' the result set are always unsorted:

```
item 4
item 3 
item 1 
item 2
```

All document items are proper returned, but never sorted.

It only works if I code the function to sort the results object:

```
results = sorted(results, key=lambda k: k.order_id)
```

But It does not looks to be the proper way once the sort is already an argument of the query object.

I would thanking you all for any sort of clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying this on your local dev server? According to [this ticket](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7456&q=index%20direction&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log) the direction functionality doesn't work locally but should work as expected when deployed.